# compiling PHP fails cause of libpcre

Tags: php, make, configure

I'm trying to compile PHP myself as I want to use PHPBrew to switch between multiple versions of PHP.

I already solved a ton of problems in the process, but with this particular one I can't get any further. I'm getting this error message in the `make` process:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/libpcre.a(pcre_exec.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_pcre_ucd_stage1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/libpcre.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libphp5.5.5.la] Fehler 1
Error
```

I needed to add a symlink from `/usr/libpcre.a -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.a` before, as otherwise he would complain about not beeing able to find `libpcre.a`.

I also tried to add `"EXTRACFLAGS=-fPIC"` to `make`, but it wouldn't change anything. It's the first time I'm compiling something, so I'm not even sure if I get the basics right.

This is under Ubuntu 13.10 (not seeing the same problems on 12.04). This is my PHPBrew command:

```
phpbrew install 5.5.5 +default+mysql+pdo+apxs2
```

Wich results in the following configure options being generated:

> ./configure '--prefix=/home/malte/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.5'
>   '--with-config-file-path=/home/malte/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.5/etc'
>   '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/home/malte/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.5/var/db' '--with-pear=/home/malte/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.5/lib/php'
>   '--disable-all' '--enable-phar' '--enable-session'
>   '--enable-short-tags' '--enable-tokenizer' '--with-pcre-regex'
>   '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-libdir=lib/i386-linux-gnu'
>   '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd'
>   '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-pdo'
>   '--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2' '--enable-dom' '--enable-libxml'
>   '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader'
>   '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-xsl' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr'
>   '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-cli'
>   '--enable-ctype' '--enable-dom' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-filter'
>   '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm'
>   '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-json' '--enable-mbregex'
>   '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mhash' '--with-mcrypt=/usr'
>   '--enable-pcntl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-pcre-dir=/usr'
>   '--enable-phar' '--enable-posix' '--with-readline=/usr'
>   '--enable-sockets' '--enable-tokenizer' '--enable-zip' 2>&1 >
>   /home/malte/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.5/build.log

I think I have all relevant packages installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep pcre
libpcre++0:amd64                install
libpcre3:amd64                  install
libpcre3:i386                   install
libpcre3-dev:amd64              install
libpcrecpp0:amd64               install
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: use the command file to find out if /usr/libpcre.a is 32bit or 64bit please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rebuild `libpcre` with position independent code. The straightforward way to do that is to build or install the `libpcre` shared objects (e.g. `libpcre.so`) which are built with `-fPIC`.

Since the library archive was in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, the shared objects might be there also. Try adding `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `LDFLAGS` of php. This will also save you from symlinking to /usr.

Comment: Perfect. This solved it.